# attach multiple events to a dom element at once

Tags: javascript, arrays, addeventlistener

So I was trying to attach both hashChange and load events at once to the window object so that I don't have to repeat the same window.addEventListener syntax all over the place.

here is what I tried :

```
["hashChange", "load"].forEach(ev => {
  window.addEventListener(ev,doSomething);
});
```

and realized that only the load event was handled.
so I tried a more imperative approach:

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", showRecipe);
window.addEventListener("load", showRecipe);
```

which worked. However, I still do not like how I had to explicitly write it that way. How can I solve this please?

EDIT: i realized i had an inconsistency with the syntax of the hash change event. can't believe the solution was as trivial as that given that i had to sit for hours wondering if it was a javascript bug lol. Anyways, thanks guys. This definitely went a long way :)

Comment: there's a difference between `hashChange` and `hashchange` - perhaps that's the reason

Comment: Yes, I agree, running the `forEach` with the corrected event name works.